# How to match two contours in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have two images. Both the images contains same texts. My reference image has complete texts and my source image contains the texts in cropped form and some time drawn in angle. Now i have the contours of both the images. how can i compare both the contours?

Comment: What do you mean by compare?

Comment: I just want to check whether the source image is available in reference or not. so am trying with contours.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a rigid registration between the two image.  Choose one that captures the deformations you have, specifically translation and rotation.  Once the transform is known you can accurately position the cropped image on the full sized image.  You can then do a subtraction between them to discover differences in the text.